# How can I multiply two sparse Matrix, without using numpy in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, time-complexity, sparse-matrix, multiplication

I am new into programming and I am using for the first time stackoverflow so Hi to everyone! So, this is the reason why am I asking this:
I am trying to multiply two sparse Matrix without numpy or other functions that might help me from python libraries. I am using a list as the Data Structure for storing the non zero elements. Each non zero elements is a Class which has as attributes row, col and the value. The list contains only those instances of the class _MatrixElement. I want to perform this computation not in a complexity of O(n^3), as it makes no sense to go through each line of both matrix and do the math behind because most of the elements are 0.
This is the piece of code I wrote so far:

```
 class _MatrixElement:
      def __init__(self, row ,col, value):
          self.row = row
          self.col = col
          self.value = value

 class SparseMatrix:
      def __init__(self, numRows, numCols):
          self._numRows = numRows
          self._numCols = numCols
          self._elementList = list()
    
      def numRows(self):
          return self._numRows
    
      def numCols(self):
          return self._numCols

      def __setitem__(self, ndxTuple, scalar):
          ndx = self._findPosition(ndxTuple[0], ndxTuple[1])
          if ndx is not None:
              if scalar != 0.0:
                  self._elementList[ndx].value = scalar
              else:
                  self._elementList.pop(ndx)
          else:
              if scalar != 0.0:
                  element = _MatrixElement(ndxTuple[0], ndxTuple[1], scalar)
                  self._elementList.append(element)

      def __getitem__(self, row, col):
          assert row >= 0 and row < self.numRows(), "Subscript out of range"
          assert col >= 0 and col < self.numCols(), "Subscript out of range"
          ndx = self._findPosition(row, col)
          if ndx is not None:
              return self._elementList[ndx]
          else:
              raise Exception("The element is not in the matrix")

      def _findPosition(self, row, col):
          """Find the position of the non zero element in the list, using the row and col as parameters"""
          n = len(self._elementList)
          for i in range(n):
              if (row == self._elementList[i].row and
                  col == self._elementList[i].col):
                  return i
         return None

      def transpose(self):
          newTransposeMatrix = SparseMatrix(numRows=self.numCols(), numCols=self.numRows())
          for elem in self._elementList:
              tmp_row = elem.row
              elem.row = elem.col
              elem.col = tmp_row
              newTransposeMatrix._elementList.append(elem)
          return newTransposeMatrix

      def __mul__(self, otherMatrix):
          assert isinstance(otherMatrix, SparseMatrix), "Wrong matrix type"
          assert self.numCols() == otherMatrix.numRows(), "The two matrices can't be multiplied"
          transpMatrix = otherMatrix.transpose()
          sparseNewMatrix = SparseMatrix(numRows=self.numRows(), numCols=otherMatrix.numRows())
          for apos in range(len(self._elementList)):
              r = self._elementList[apos].row
              for bpos in range(len(transpMatrix._elementList)):
                   c = transpMatrix._elementList[bpos].row
                   tmpa = apos
                   tmpb = bpos
                   the_sum = 0
                   while (tmpa < len(self._elementList) and (tmpb < len(transpMatrix._elementList)) and (self._elementList[tmpa].row == r
                                                                                                  and transpMatrix._elementList[tmpb].row == c)):
                         if self._elementList[tmpa].col > transpMatrix._elementList[tmpb].col:
                               tmpa += 1
                          elif self._elementList[tmpa].col < transpMatrix._elementList[tmpb].col:
                               tmpb += 1
                          else:
                               the_sum += self._elementList[tmpa].value * transpMatrix._elementList[tmpb].value
                               tmpa += 1
                               tmpb += 1
            if the_sum != 0:
                sparseNewMatrix.add(_MatrixElement(r, c, the_sum))
         return sparseNewMatrix
```

Later EDIT:
I have improved my algorithm using as guide the algorithm from this website[link here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operations-sparse-matrices/?ref=lbp) and after I run my program, the result is the following one:

```
1 2 10
1 1 96
2 1 2
2 2 5
2 1 16
```

In big lines, the result is correct. The only problem is that I cannot understand why the program does not sum 2 1 2 with 2 1 1 16.
The result comes from the following input:

```
Row Col Val      Row Col Val
1   2   10       1   1   2
1   3   12       1   2   5
2   1   1        2   2   1
2   3   2        3   1   8
```

After second matrix is transposed we'll have:

```
Row Col Val      Row Col Val
1   2   10       1   1   2
1   3   12       1   3   8
2   1   1        2   1   5
2   3   2        2   2   1
```

The result should be:

```
1   1   96 
1   2   10 
2   1   18  
2   2   5
```

However my result is different from the one I should get. Can somebody explain why that sum is not performed?

If somebody can help, I would be very grateful! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Which kind of multiply?  Element-wise or matrix?  In the `scipy.sparse` implementation, most math is performed with the `csr` format.  That in turn was based on theory and code that was developed years ago for finite element types of computations, most likely in Fortran.

Comment: You might get more help on the `Computational Science` board, which takes a more generic approach computations like this.  SO is oriented more toward debugging issues, using maximal use of Python libraries like `numpy` and `scipy`.

Comment: To multply two matrix of (mxn size and pxq size) which are Sparse Matrices. I read about scipy.sparse implementaton and I found some answers. My point is not use this for further problems, but to understand the concept behind and how can I reduce the complexity of the classical multiplication of two matrix. Thank you so much for your answer! I will give a try! Thank youuu a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scipy.sparse implementation can be used.
also, you can use this algorithm [[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operations-sparse-matrices/)][1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operations-sparse-matrices/)

Comment: Thank you so much Namjoo! This is it. I was thinking of this logic, but I did not understand how should I compute the position where the result should be placed in the newly formed Matrix. Thank you a lot!